# Is there any difference in the view of process & sub process between command “/bin/sh -c ls /” and sh temp.sh(containing one line ls / only)?

Tags: linux, bash, c

What is the difference between the above ways of executing command and the code below?

`#include 
int main ( ) 
{
   int return_value;
   return_value = system ( "ls /" );
   return return_value;
}`

Answer (score 0):

`system("ls /")` will spawn a `sh` process, giving it the arguments `-c` and `ls /`. So the main difference between running your program and typing `sh -c "ls /"` at a shell is that in the first case, there is also a process containing your program. So if you could capture the process tree while `ls` was running, you would see something like this:

```
init───konsole───bash───myprog───sh───ls
```

instead of

```
init───konsole───bash───sh───ls
```

If you used one of the `exec` family of functions, you could avoid the use of `sh` altogether and replace your program with the `ls` utility. In that case, you would see:

```
init───konsole───bash───ls
```

The program might look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  return execlp("ls", "ls", "/");
}
```

Many shells -- including `bash` -- will do this automatically if the command executed through the `-c` option is a simple command. Even so, there is little point spawning a shell for the purpose of replacing the shell with a process which you could just `exec`.

There is very little difference between `sh -c "ls -l"` and `sh ls-l.sh`, other than whatever is needed to open the file for reading.

Comment: If I use one of the _exec_ family of functions, the process tree should be like:`init───konsole───bash───myprog───ls`

Comment: Am I right or I misunderstand this process?

Comment: @user3872279 No, `exec` *replaces* your process with the `exec`ed process. The `exec` call only returns if there was an error which prevented it from working (like not being able to find the indicated program). It's quite different from `system`, which does return.